# Flatpak downloads more than originally intended

Tags: 22.04, flatpak

In the lines number 1, 6, 7, 8 Flatpak downloaded less than initially intended, which is understandable: some parts of the bundle were already present on my system. But why did it download more than originally intended in lines 2, 3, 4, 5?

```
 1. [✓] com.github.wwmm.easyeffects.Locale                        stable             i             flathub              7.6 kB / 888.2 kB
 2. [✓] org.freedesktop.LinuxAudio.Plugins.Calf                   22.08              i             flathub             15.2 MB / 11.8 MB
 3. [✓] org.freedesktop.LinuxAudio.Plugins.LSP                    22.08              i             flathub             12.9 MB / 12.6 MB
 4. [✓] org.freedesktop.LinuxAudio.Plugins.MDA                    22.08              i             flathub              3.1 MB / 2.3 MB
 5. [✓] org.freedesktop.LinuxAudio.Plugins.ZamPlugins             22.08              i             flathub             80.4 MB / 79.9 MB
 6. [✓] org.gnome.Platform.Locale                                 44                 i             flathub             17.8 kB / 340.5 MB
 7. [✓] org.gnome.Platform                                        44                 i             flathub            196.7 MB / 326.4 MB
 8. [✓] com.github.wwmm.easyeffects                               stable             i             flathub             13.7 MB / 14.4 MB
```

I'm obviously not worried about the download size itself. I'm curious about how it is possible within the Flatpak architecture. What made it change its mind?

Comment: @David What OP means is e.g. this  15.2 MB / 11.8 MB and it is provided in the question.

Comment: @David Scroll the grey rectangle to the right and look at the last (rightmost) column.